# How to format XMPP message stanza to GCM using C++ - xmpp handshake

Tags: android, c++, unix, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

Handshake is complete and received `<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>` from GCM xmpp connection.
Now, I am formatting and sending send-to-sync message from APP server to GCM to be sent to mobile device, as follows

```
ostringstream sync;
sync << "<message id=\"1234\">";
sync << "<gcm xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\">";
sync << " { ";
sync << "\"to\":\"eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci\",";
sync << " \"message_id\":\"1234\",";
sync << " \"time_to_live\":" << 10;
sync << " } ";
sync << "</gcm></message>";
string msg = sync.str();
sslSock_->write(msg.c_str(), msg.length());
std::string syncResp = readFromGcm(); // ack/nack
```

Unfortunately, SSL socket is closing and no ack received. Any idea, what am I doing wrong here?

Actual message I am trying to send looks as follows

`Sending msg=<message id="150827111504042682"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data"> { "to":"eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci", "message_id":"150827111504042682", "time_to_live":10 } </gcm></message>`

Do I need to send any ack after receipt of success msg from GCM and before sending any stanza?
or Do I need to add new line characters after curly braces and name value pairs?

flow of messages

`Sent1: <stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' version='1.0' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
Received1: <stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="EBA37684C852364D" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
Received2: <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
Sent2: <auth mechanism='PLAIN' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>ADM2NTU4MjFZVV0F1LVJV</auth>
Received3: <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
Sent3: <message id=""><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"to":"eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci","message_id":"150827161659237590","data":{"title":"Alert: mydata","text":"mydata refresh"},"time_to_live":10,"delay_while_idle":true,"delivery_receipt_requested":true}</gcm></message>
Received4: None. Socket closed`

I just noticed that device token (eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci) has got colon in it? Do I need to convert it in to something so that google xmpp processor do not get confused with json colon ("to":"deviceToken")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/rawxmpp
and
http://grokbase.com/p/gg/android-gcm/13a2zrnn34/gcm-ccs-xmpp-3rd-party-server-implementation

another example of xmpp handshake
https://tech.yandex.com/disk/doc/dg/concepts/xmpp_xmpp-connection-docpage/

Thanks to Lee Chua who asked the question. It is not clear who answered unfortunately though many thanks to the person who answered it finally.
Not sure why protocol is not documented in the right place.

`C (authenticate):
 <stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' version='1.0' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
 <auth mechanism='PLAIN' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>base64Enc(\0[userName]\0[password])</auth>
S:
  <stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="352584B87B657F7F" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
  <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
C (pre Binding):
  <stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
S:
  <stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="7C0C770AED97331C" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:features><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
C: (bind):
  <iq type='set' id='bind-1' to='gcm.googleapis.com'> <bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'> <resource>core</resource> </bind> </iq>
S:
  <iq from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="bind-1" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>[senderID]@gcm.googleapis.com/coreAB8CB2E7</jid></bind></iq>
C: (session request):
  <iq to='gcm.googleapis.com' type='set' id='sess_1'> <session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/> </iq>
S: single byte message and then
S: <iq from="gcm.googleapis.com" type="result" id="sess_1"/>
C: first stanza sent successfully`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma at the end of:

`sync << "'to':'eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci'";`,

it should be like this to be valid:

`sync << "'to':'eA_hcHITvwo:APA91bEB83Gci',";`

maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Do I need to send any ack after receipt of success msg from GCM?

Comment: For each message your app server receives from CCS, it needs to send an ACK message. It never needs to send a NACK message. If you don’t send an ACK for a message, CCS will just resend it.

Do you get any NACK error messages in return? Can you try change JSON single quotes to double quotes by escaping them ("\"") because JSON does not validate single quote string though I don't know how google is handling XMPP JSON.

Comment: I tried using double quotes instead but no luck. Also tried sending ack after success msg from authentication but still no luck.

Comment: I just noticed that device token has got colon in it? Do I need to convert it in to something so that google xmpp processor do not get confused with json colon?